# Como conectar um script feito em PHP LDAP com AD do Windows utilizando conexão SSL?

Tags: php, windows, xampp, active-directory, openldap

Tenho o código em PHP LDAP para alterar senha no Active Directory:

```
<?php

$usuario="xxx";
$senha_atual="0000";
$senha_nova="11111";
$pessoas="casa.cafe.br";
$servidor="1.1.1.1";
$porta=389;
$portas=636;
$base="CN=$usuario,CN=Users,DC=casa,DC=cafe,DC=br";
$rdn=$usuario."@".$pessoas;

$con = @ldap_connect("ldap://".$servidor, $portas) or die("Erro na conexao ao servidor {$servidor}");
if ($con) {

    ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $bind = ldap_bind($con, $rdn, $senha_atual);
    echo "Passou do ldap_bind($con, $usuario."@".$pessoas, $senha_atual);";
    // verify binding
    if ($bind) {

            $userdata["mail"] = "usuario111@cafe.br";
            $userdata["unicodepwd"] = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', "\"".$senha_nova."\"" );

            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($userdata);
            echo "</pre>";

            $rs = ldap_modify($con, $base, $userdata);

            echo "<br><br>";
            ldap_get_option($con,LDAP_OPT_ERROR_STRING,$error);
            echo $error;
            echo "<br><br>";

            if ($rs) {

                  $msg="Senha foi atualizada com sucesso!";

              }else{

                  $msg="Ocorreu um erro ao trocar a senha! Contate o Administrador.";

              }

    } else {

         $msg="Usuario inexistente ou senha incorreta! Tente novamente.";

    }
}
?>
```

Quando tento alterar a senha do usuário mostra a seguinte mensagem:

> Warning: ldap_modify(): Modify: Server is unwilling to perform in

Usando o código:

`ldap_get_option($con,LDAP_OPT_ERROR_STRING,$error);`

`echo $error;`

Mostra essa mensagem:

> 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A129B, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

Pesquisando encontrei soluções que dizem que para conseguir alterar a senha preciso de uma conexão SSL do PHP com o AD do Windows, como posso configurar o PHP da minha máquina local que está rodando XAMPP e o AD do Windows para conseguir conectar via SSL?

obs.:
Utilizando o XAMPP com PHP Version 7.1.1 (Máquina Local) e Windows Server 2012(Servidor da Rede).

Comment: Coloca a tag windows pra chamar a galera que comece melhor AD. Fiquei curioso com essa pergunta

Comment: acabei de colocar @Daniel, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Amigo primeiramente o SSL tem que estar configurado no seu server LDAP. Feito essa configuração existe 2 detalhes a serem percebidos o link ldap:// ficará com S no final ldaps://... E é necessário que o certificado também esteja do lado cliente, configura o caminho dele como uma variável de ambiente! Fazendo certo isso funciona :)

```
<?php

putenv('LDAPTLS_CACERT=./ca.pem'); //caminho para o seu CERTIFICADO
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

//AS LINHAS ACIMA DEVE IR ANTES DO SEU ldap_connect() 

$l = ldap_connect("ldaps://ldap/"); //ATENTE-SE AO LDAPS
ldap_set_option($l, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_bind($l, "cn=SeuCN,dc=SeuDC", "xxxxxxx");
echo(ldap_error($l)."\n");
$s = ldap_search($l, "dc=SeuDC", "uid=test");
echo(ldap_count_entries($l, $s)."\n");
?>
```

Comment: oi @anderson-souza quando colocar o ldaps no ldap_connect mostra o seguinte erro:

"Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in"

Comment: Colocou o certificado na sua maquina ? seu LDAP suporta SSL?

Comment: Ainda não tenho o certificado, você tem um tutorial que ensine a configurar o certificado tanto no lado cliente como no servidor windows?

Comment: Ai é necessário transferir essa pergunta para a Windows, pedir para os caras te explicar como fazer isso e gerar o certificado. Feito isso vc volta para a sua aplicação